# What does linking my my2K account do?

Tags: mafia-3

I linked my my2K account to Mafia 3. What does linking an account do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [2K FAQ](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/201335163-my2K-Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> my2K is a user account system used across a variety of 2K products. Currently, it appears in a handful of our recent mobile games, as well as the official 2K website.

For XCOM 2, linking your my2K account does [the following](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/216687047-How-Do-I-Use-my2K-with-XCOM-2-):

> Connecting your my2K account to XCOM 2 will eventually allow you to **keep track of your in-game statistics**.

For Evolve, from [here](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/204430213-my2K-in-Evolve), linking your account does this:

> The biggest question we've received is "Why should I connect to my2K?" my2K provides some benefits for players looking to improve their game in Evolve. Not only does it **allow the Evolve Game Changer website access to your game info and provide you with detailed analytics on your gameplay**, it also lets you connect to the Hunters Quest mobile app. Hunters Quest lets players unlock exclusive and speeds up the character mastery progress.

---

Based on the way it interacts with the aforementioned games, linking your account in Mafia 3 will most likely track your in-game statistics so that you can view them.